# Discrete Fourier transform of sampled sin function nothing like continuous?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

So I'm a little confused about what is going on with the discrete Fourier transform.

I tested out discrete Fourier transform with a little python script on a sin function

```
import os
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 20)

y = np.zeros(20)
y[:] = np.sin(2*np.pi*x/20)

g = np.fft.fft(y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(g)
```

I was expecting a single blip at 1 but instead I get something thats non zero everywhere.
[image]

What is going on?

**Edit:**

I did not use linspace correctly, if I wanted $n \in 0 \ldots 20 $ then I should have done linspace(0,20, 21) for that. Anyway, If I instead do this

```
x = np.linspace(0, 19, 20)

y = np.zeros(20)
y[:] = np.sin(2*np.pi*x/20)

g = np.fft.fft(y)
```

Now I have 20 samples, and a sin of angular frequency $\frac{2 \pi}{20}$

and I get this plot
[image]

Which is better because its almost zero in the middle, but there is still this strange behavior where it dips negative around the 0th frequency. Also shouldn't there be 2 peaks because the complex part needs to be cancelled? And isn't the zeroth frequency corresponding to $e^0$?

**Edit 2:**

I have literally no idea what changed but it works now. Firstly, I was supposed too be getting zero when I plotted g because the fft of a real sin is only imaginary, so idk how I was even getting a real fft to begin with. Anyway, that's gone now. Nothing in my code is different from the second edit.

When I multiply the fft by -1j I get this graph now[image]
which is correct

Comment: Try `x = np.linspace(0, 20, 20, endpoint=False)`.

Comment: So you are computing the FFT of $y(n) = \sin(2\pi n/20)$, $n \in 0 \ldots 20$ not $n \in 0 \ldots 19$. Since $20$ isn't a multiple of $21$ you get aliasing when periodizing the FT of $\sin(2\pi t/20)$.

Comment: Ok I fixed that, check out my edit

Comment: Use a for loop to create y instead of loosing your time with linspace. With $y(n) = \sin(2\pi n/20),n \in 0 \ldots 19$ then its FFT will be two peaks at $k =1, 19$ (proof : $2i\sin(x) = e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$ then geometric sum)

Comment: ok I got a correct answer check my edit. idk how I even got a graph for g when the fourier transform is supposed to be only imaginary.